# Entity Framework update statement causing error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
 public bool UpdateValues(String impR, String actR, String proR, String impV, String magV)
 {
        bool IsInserted = false;

        try
        {
            MatrixValues c = cecbContext.MatrixValues.First(i => i.actv_reference == actR); // primary key
            c = cecbContext.MatrixValues.First(i => i.impt_reference == impR); // primary key
            c = cecbContext.MatrixValues.First(i => i.proj_reference == proR); // primary key

            c.mtrxV_importance = double.Parse(impV); // updated value
            c.mtrxV_magnitude = double.Parse(magV);  // updated value

            cecbContext.SaveChanges();  // getting an error here!!!

            IsInserted = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            IsInserted = false;
        }

        return IsInserted;
    }
```

I'm getting an error when trying to update details

Error is

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MatrixValues'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MatrixValues'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the object `c` multiple times; if the last statement is enough; then do not use the previous ones; if you want to select the `c` object using multiple criterias you need to change the following lines;

```
MatrixValues c = cecbContext.MatrixValues.First(i => i.actv_reference == actR); // primary key
  c = cecbContext.MatrixValues.First(i => i.impt_reference == impR); // primary key
  c = cecbContext.MatrixValues.First(i => i.proj_reference == proR); // primary key
```

to:

```
MatrixValues c = cecbContext.MatrixValues.First(i => i.actv_reference == actR && c.impt_reference == impR && c.proj_reference == proR);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MatrixValues'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MatrixValues'

This means the field contains Primary Key. It won't allow duplicate entries

Comment: Can you tell me how to update values, i dont want to update primary keys, i want to update only two values fields